# Upgrading code to IOS5 Storyboard... self.view assignments not working

Tags: ios5, uiview, storyboard, self

I'm new to this and couldn't find an answer. 
On my old 4.x app, I added files in which I implemented my own UIView, where I ran some "drawRect:(CGRect)rect" to paint some lines. For example...

```
/// DrawView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DrawView : UIView <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
...
}
-(void)DoSomething;
@end
```

Then, in my view controller .m file, after importing DrawView.h, I could do this:

```
self.view = (DrawView *)self.view;
[(DrawView *)self.view DoSomething];
```

Worked like a charm in my IOS4 stuff. Now that I try an IOS5 app using storyboard, this trick no longer works.

The first line...

```
self.view = (DrawView *)self.view;
```

doesn't crash. But I don't see any painting on the screen. Was expecting drawRect to show some stuff. Nothing. So I doubt the assignment was successful, or something is hidden somewhere.

The second line...

```
[(DrawView *)self.view DoSomething];
```

returns the following error:

**-[UIView DoSomething]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x87631b0
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all**

Program received signal SIGABRT

I've read somewhere that drawRect (for painting) can't run directly on the viewcontroller, and has to run on a separate instantiated implementation of UIView. That's why I do this. But apparently my old trick for assigning a custom view to the controller's self.view no longer works.

Do you know how to do this? I mean, when using storyboards and all?

Thanks

Comment: I think this might work:  
    DrawView *myView = [[[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];  
    [self.view addSubview:myView];  
    [myView DoSomething];  
  
That seems to work. If there's a better way, please post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any other options. So I'll post this as the answer. Feel free to comment or post better alternatives if you know any...

```
DrawView *myView = [[[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease]; 
[self.view addSubview:myView]; 
[myView DoSomething];
```

In my case I actually declared *myView in the .h file, then synthesized it, removed the "autorelease", and released it dealloc.